# key of Container "vanishes" when trying to get its size

Tags: flutter, layout, key

I am trying to get the size of a container whith a function that typically works. Now it fails according to the debugger because it cannot find the container's key in the widget tree. The error is **The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null. Receiver: null** I do see the key in `getSize()` but when stepping into the error throwing line, I find the explanation that it cannot find the widget if null is returned. Any idea why this is so?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}


class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>  {
  GlobalKey _keyScreenContainer = GlobalKey(); // <-------- key declared
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            key: _keyScreenContainer,         // <--------- key allocated
            width: 20, height: 20,
            child: Text("${getSize(_keyScreenContainer, context)}"),
            )
      );
  }
  
  Size getSize(GlobalKey _key, BuildContext context) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject(); // <---- error
    final boxSize = renderBox.size;
    print (boxSize);
    return boxSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but can you try your key without underscore(_):

keyScreenContainer

and

getSize(GlobalKey key, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are calling the getSize function even before the build is complete. You may call the function once widget layout is complete either in initState with WidgetsBinding.instance
.addPostFrameCallback((_) => someFunction()) or from with something like a button. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}


class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget>  {
  GlobalKey _keyScreenContainer = GlobalKey();
  
  @override
  void initState(){
    
            super.initState();
    
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => print("${getSize(_keyScreenContainer, context)}"));
    
  }
   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
          Container(
            key: _keyScreenContainer,     
            width: 20, height: 20,
            child: Text("abc"),
      ), RaisedButton(onPressed:(){
            print("${getSize(_keyScreenContainer, context)}");
            
            
          },child:Text("Get size"))]);
  }
  
  Size getSize(GlobalKey key, BuildContext context) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = key.currentContext.findRenderObject(); // <---- error
    final boxSize = renderBox.size;
    print (boxSize);
    return boxSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: This, absolutely, makes sense. I was wondering why getSize worked on a different page, but now looking into it again, I recognize that it is called there only after tapping a button. Cheers!